# DB2/JDBC database: Possible to join a transaction?

Tags: database, jdbc, transactions, db2

I am working on an application, A, that starts a database transaction, does some work, then calls a remote system, B, which in turn calls back to A. The processing of this web service call (on site A) also carries out some DB operations. Now, it would be nice if both the initial work done on site A as well as the work done as part of processing the web service call on site A, would be done in the same database transaction so they could see each others data, have their updates committed/rolled back together, not cause blocking due to cursor stability etc. Is there a standard way to achieve this? For instance, is it possible to extract a "transaction ID" from an open transaction, then include that in the web service calls, and use that transaction ID to "join" the already open transaction? Or does one have to implement such a mechanism manually (i.e. managing the transactions and the underlying object in a framework which could then execute requests on behalf of the rest of the code, and which could support such a "transaction ID" functionality)? It seems to be a fairly common requirement, so I am thinking there might be a standard way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you describe is called a distributed transaction. It requires an extra piece of software, a *transaction manager* (TM), to handle coordination of *resource managers* (DB2 in this case acts as a resource manager). The manual has a [conceptual overview of distributed transactions](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.2pc.doc/doc/c0004558.html), as well as details on how to configure DB2 and applications for distributed transactions.

From the database point of view the separate requests (in your example the initial work in A and a call-back from B) will still initiate separate units of work, but the TM will ensure they are committed or rolled back atomically.

Comment: OK regarding your last remark, so this means that the different requests cannot see each other, i.e. they are not truly running in the same transaction? And if the DB is set up for cursor stability, the work done by the first requests can actually block the table for simply selects done by the second request because that is running in a different transaction?

Comment: A unit of work has a session (connection) scope, so yes, a different connection will have a different unit of work always, and yes, there is a chance that they block one another. Generally you don't want locks to be held during an external activity (your call to remote system B), so you may need to rethink your implementation approach.

Comment: Great, thanks for clarifying. I agree the design is not optimal, but it is nonetheless good to know that the correct approach is to redesign the overall flow rather than trying to solve it at the DB level.